# A generic Validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validate plugin. I have a repeated requirement of enable disable textbox on on checkbox or radiobutton and only if checked it will be required. Can you help me to create a generic script for the same.

```
<table class="list-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="50"><input type="radio" name="radio2" id="ownAcc" class="required"/></td>
            <td width="200">Own Account</td>
            <td class="last"><select class="dropdown" id="ownAccDD"><option>Select</option></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="alt-row">
            <td><input type="radio" name="radio2" /></td>
            <td>Registered 3rd Party Account</td>
            <td class="last"><select class="dropdown"><option>Select</option></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="radio2" id="unreg" /></td>
            <td>Unregistered Account</td>
            <td class="last"><input type="text" name="uregacc" class="text-box dependent" />
                    <span class="hintmsg">
                        (Enter the 13-digit account number)
                    </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <span class="hintmsg"><b>Note:</b>Transaction limit is only applicable for registered and unregistered 3rd party account fund transfer.</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: nobody will provide code your or neither will anybody do your work. stackoverflow is meant so solve problems not to do the work of other people.

Comment: I know its a wrong way to approach sorry :(

Comment: Start you own code, look which problems you have with that and then you can ask, but if you never provide some code with a problem you have, nobody will anwer that

Comment: are you using this plugin http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/?

Answer (score 0):

Well in this case you can add a custom validator to your jquery validation plugin which will work according to your requirements.